# Gradle - Multi project with common module dependencies

Tags: java, android, gradle, kotlin, build.gradle

I have created a 'backend' gradle project (a server) that is including a 'base' project dependency like:

`build.gradle (:backend)`

```
dependencies { implementation project(':base') }
```

`settings.gradle (:backend)`

```
rootProject.name = 'backend'

include ':base'
project(':base').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../base')
```

I can open the 'backend' project and run it without any problems.

As you might understand from the '../base' in the settings file, the 'base' project is one level above.
On that level, I have another project set up like this:

`settings.gradle (:OneLevelAbove)`

```
rootProject.name='OneLevelAbove'
include ':app', ':base', ':SharedCode', ':backend'
```

I get no errors from the IDE anywhere and my other projects run just fine, utilizing code from ':base'.

However, my problem is that when I now try to run the ':backend' project from here instead, I get a crash:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: path/to/base/project/Class
    at server.ServerKt.main(Server.kt:23)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: path.to.base.project.Class
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

If I remove all code related to ':base' the server works fine, so I guess there is a problem with the inclusion, or maybe the classpath.

I'm new to gradle, so I'm wondering how to set it up properly to be able to run the server from the 'OneLevelAbove' project, also utilizing code from ':base'.

Thank you in advance.